# Can we create pure functions in Fortran which generate random numbers?

Tags: random, concurrency, fortran, gfortran

My goal is to write a pure function using random numbers which can be used in a DO CONCURRENT structure. The compiler does not seem to permit this.

```
mwe.f95:8:30:

             call init_seed ( )
                              1
Error: Subroutine call to ‘init_seed’ at (1) is not PURE
mwe.f95:9:36:

             call random_number ( y )
                                    1
Error: Subroutine call to intrinsic ‘random_number’ at (1) is not PURE
mwe.f95:16:8:

     use myFunction
        1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘myfunction.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Why is this so and is there a way to generate random numbers in a pure routine?

The MWE follows. Compilation command is `gfortran mwe.f95`. Compiler version is GCC 5.1.0.

```
module myFunction

    implicit none

contains
    pure real function action ( ) result ( new_number )
        real :: y
            call init_seed ( )
            call random_number ( y )
            new_number = y**2
    end function
end module myFunction


program mwe
    use myFunction
    implicit none
    real :: x

        x = action ( )

end program mwe
```

Comment: Best I know, pure functions cannot have side effects. Calls to PRNG APIs typically do have a side effect, namely updating the internal state of the PRNG.

Comment: consider precomputing an array of random values before the `do concurrent` construct, then in the concurrent loop you'd have something like `x(i)=action(randarray(i))`, with `action` being a proper pure function.

Comment: We may be able to help you best (beyond Vlad's very good answer) if we understood *why* you are keen to have a pure function in this case.

Comment: @agentp: Thank you. My comments to VF were written before I read this.

Comment: @Ross: One goal for this code is to evaluate the DO CONCURRENT performance across different compilers and different HPCs. For now the scheme is similar to the suggestion of agentp which has the fringe benefit of creating a list of random numbers which can be used as  a fiducial across different machines.

Comment: There is another possibility: use SIMD instead of concurrency. But you might have to introduce some structural changes. You can then use IMPURE ELEMENTALs instead of PURE procedures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is completely against the concept of pureness. True pure functions, as found in true functional languages, should always return the same result for the same input. Fortran pure functions can read module variables and therefore are more complex.

It is not even a good idea to have any function, not just a pure function, to return pseudo-random numbers. When you have more function calls in an expression the Fortran compiler is permitted to evaluate the function just once. That is even more likely, or better justified, when that function is pure.

I would suggest to just use regular DO loops and call `random_number` or other custom PRNG subroutine. Even if you want automatic parallelization or similar , the compilers are normally capable to treat regular DO loops equally well as DO CONCURRENT.

Comment: Great explanation. What do you think about preloading a vector with random numbers and then generating a random number is replaced by grabbing an array entry inside DO CONCURRENT?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need pure random number generator. It is quite possible to make, say, for Linear Congruential Generator, where seed (being 64bit unsigned integer) is the same as state and is the same as return value. In that case state/seed is kept externally outside the sampling routine, passed explicitly and on getting it back from RNG is stored

Comment: I suppose in the `do concurrent` context you would need to maintain a vector of different seeds for each of the concurrent instances.

Comment: That function would have to return a derived type containing the generated number and the new state, but yes, that would be possible. I would still prefer a subroutine much much more. The PRNG am using (not in do concurrent) actually does accept something like this, but in OpenMP and I have to take care about keeping the state of each thread separate.

Comment: @agentp In the `do concurrent` context you have to maintain vector of seeds/states anyway whether RNG is pure or not

Comment: @agentp: We rely on the standard trick of using the pid to generate a seed.  We also have built in an option to use a seed from the system by reading /dev/urandom. It is not clear if this is suitable for concurrent computation. Comments would be appreciated.

Comment: @dantopa We used to run with RNG which has fast (logarithmic) skip-ahead (a.k.a. discard, a.k.a. leap-frog) feature. Thus you start with one seed but different threads skip ahead in different way, something along the way `discard(thread_id*SKIP_PER_THREAD)`

Comment: @dantopa This is the RNG I'm talking about, it is pretty much the same as in MCNP5 https://github.com/mit-crpg/openmc/blob/develop/src/random_lcg.F90. It has fast log2(N) skip-ahead (aka discard). If you make seed/state as an external parameter, you could convert code into pure function suitable for `concurrent` context