# How to call a Fortran intrinsic from a pure function?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have the following function that generates random integers, and which I need to be pure:

```
pure function rand_int(n,m)

! generates a random integer from a discrete uniform distribution between n and m.

    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n, m
    real(8) :: x
    integer :: rand_int

    call random_number(x)

    rand_int = ceiling((m-n+1)*x) + n - 1

end function
```

When compiling it,  `gfortran` outputs the following error message:

```
37 |   call random_number(x)
   |                       1
Error: Subroutine call to intrinsic ‘random_number’ at (1) is not PURE
```

So, is there a way to make the call to the intrinsic pure? And how?

Comment: No - you can't change the characteristics of intrinsics.  But in this case, why do you want to make `rand_int` pure?  It's inherently relying on some external state.  See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32636715/3157076) for some discussion on alternative approaches.

Comment: I just want to try it with the ```do concurrent``` loop, for no particular reason, just experimenting :)

Comment: In which case, would you consider that other question to address all the points ("you can't use `random_number`, but you can do ... instead" and especially "don't even try to do this")?  If so, I can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @francescalus I see, OK then