# Is there a straightforward way to do concurrent calculations with a random number generator in Fortran?

Tags: concurrency, fortran, gfortran

I have some finite element code I have programmed in Fortran 95 that I have optimised so that I can now get well over 16Mil. elements working under 2GB of memory footprint.

The source function for my code is not smooth so I am using a (stratified) Monte-Carlo method to integrate, which requires a random number generator to select sample locations

I have tried compiling with gfortran-9 using `-fopenmp -Ofast -ftree-parallelize-loops=4` but the loop with the random number generator won't go parallel.  I tried `do concurrent` but obviously that didn't work because `random_number` isn't 'pure'. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32637737/2372254 
I also tried blocking my loop but that didn't work either.

Here is the code I am talking about

```
        do  k=1,n_els ! total elements is n_els**2. This is block
            do i=1+ (k-1)*n_els ,k*n_els
                supp_vec = 0 
                integ_vec = 0.0_wp

                ! in this subroutine I call random_number
                call do_element(ind, n_els, i, num_points_per_strat, &
                                strat_rows, strat_cols, supp_vec, integ_vec) 
                do j=1, 4
                    sc_vec(supp_vec(j) ) = integ_vec(j)
                end do
                ! give some info about progress

                if (mod( i , (n_els**2)/10) == 0) print*, i*10/((n_els**2)/10), "% done"
            end do
        end do
```

It seems I could write blocks to a file and call `n` different instances of the routine.  I figure there must be a cleaner way to do that. Any tips on how to get that going faster?

I was considering writing a block-worth of points (depending on memory limits) to an array first and supplying that in the subroutine call.  Before I try that I thought I would see if anybody had any advice about a better way. It would be good to keep the memory footprint down where possible.

Comment: Re, "... _the_ random number generator..." I don't know Fortran or its libraries, but in most programming languages there's more than one way to do _anything_. If the random number generator that you're using doesn't meet your needs (e.g., because you can't have different instances of it to be used by different threads) then find another one that does work. In the worst case, you might have to write your own, but I'm guessing that it won't come to that.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all.Fortran questions to get much more attention

Comment: @SolomonSlow yeah thanks. It seems it isn't as hard as one would think: https://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/smallprng.html

Comment: @VladimirF ok thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 7 and newer GFortran has a parallel random number generator. When implementing it, here's the OpenMP code I used to verify that the performance indeed scales with increasing numbers of threads (from https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-12/msg02110.html ):

```
! Benchmark generating random numbers
! Janne Blomqvist 2015
program randbench
#ifdef _OPENMP
  use omp_lib
#endif
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)          ! double precision
  integer, parameter :: i64 = selected_int_kind(18) ! At least 64-bit integer

#ifdef _OPENMP
  print *, "Using up to ", omp_get_max_threads(), " threads."
#endif
  call genr4
  call genr8
contains
  subroutine genr4
    integer, parameter :: n = int(1e7)
    real, save :: r(n)
    integer :: i
    integer(i64) :: t1, t2, td
#ifdef _OPENMP
    integer :: blocks, blocksize, l, h
#endif
    Print *, "Generate default real random variables"
    call system_clock (t1)
    !$omp parallel do private(i)
    do i = 1, n
       call random_number(r(i))
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do
    call system_clock (t2)
    td = t2 - t1
    print *, "Generating ", n, " default reals individually took ", td, " ticks."
    call system_clock (t1)
#ifdef _OPENMP
    blocks = omp_get_max_threads()
    blocksize = n / blocks
    !$omp parallel do private(l,h,i)
    do i = 0, blocks - 1
       l = i * blocksize + 1
       h = l + blocksize - 1
       !print *, "Low: ", l, " High: ", h
       call random_number(r(l:h))
    end do
#else
    call random_number(r)
#endif
    Call system_clock (t2)
    print *, "Generating ", n, " default reals as an array took  ", t2-t1, &
         " ticks. => ind/arr = ", real(td, dp) / (t2-t1)
  end subroutine genr4

  subroutine genr8
    integer, parameter :: n = int(1e7)
    real(dp), save :: r(n)
    integer :: i
    integer(i64) :: t1, t2, td
#ifdef _OPENMP
    integer :: blocks, blocksize, l, h
#endif
    print *, "Generate double real random variables"
    call system_clock (t1)
    !$omp parallel do
    do i = 1, n
       call random_number(r(i))
    end do
    call system_clock (t2)
    td = t2 - t1
    print *, "Generating ", n, " double reals individually took  ", td, " ticks."
    call system_clock (t1)
#ifdef _OPENMP
    blocks = omp_get_max_threads()
    blocksize = n / blocks
    !$omp parallel do private(l,h,i)
    do i = 0, blocks - 1
       l = i * blocksize + 1
       h = l + blocksize - 1
       !print *, "Low: ", l, " High: ", h
       call random_number(r(l:h))
    end do
#else
    call random_number(r)
#endif
    call system_clock (t2)
    print *, "Generating ", n, " double reals as an array took   ", t2-t1, &
         " ticks. => ind/arr = ", real(td, dp) / (t2 -t1)
  end subroutine genr8

end program
```

Comment: That URL points out briefly that it will not be possible to reproduce results when varying number of threads with a parallel random number generator.

Comment: @tim18: With the old design it indeed wasn't possible due to thread scheduling being non-deterministic. With the current it's possible.

Comment: OK well that's an answer that makes me glad I asked. I'll have to do some further tests because for some reason it still won't go parallel, but thanks.

Comment: for some reason I still can't get this working.  Does it matter if I make my call to random from inside a subroutine inside the loop?

Comment: @Notachance: It "should" work. That being said, the code example in your question doesn't have any OpenMP directives, so unless they are there in some piece of the code you're not showing, then you'll have only one thread active.